# How to use json utf-16 in react js?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, utf-8, utf-16

I send a request to backend and the json file I get is in this format :

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"title":"slider1","photo":"\/upload\/slider\/2021\/1\/slider1\/slider1.jpg","status":1},{"id":2,"title":"slider2","photo":"\/upload\/slider\/2021\/1\/slider2\/slider2.jpg","status":1},{"id":3,"title":"\u067e\u0648\u0634\u06a9 \u0645\u0627\u06cc \u0628\u06cc \u0628\u06cc","photo":"\/upload\/slider\/2021\/1\/\u067e\u0648\u0634\u06a9 \u0645\u0627\u06cc \u0628\u06cc \u0628\u06cc\/\u067e\u0648\u0634\u06a9 \u0645\u0627\u06cc \u0628\u06cc \u0628\u06cc.png","status":1},{"id":4,"title":"\u0648\u06cc\u0698\u0647 \u06af\u06cc \u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0645\u0627\u06cc \u0628\u06cc \u0628\u06cc","photo":"\/upload\/slider\/2021\/1\/\u0648\u06cc\u0698\u0647 \u06af\u06cc \u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0645\u0627\u06cc \u0628\u06cc \u0628\u06cc\/\u0648\u06cc\u0698\u0647 \u06af\u06cc \u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0645\u0627\u06cc \u0628\u06cc \u0628\u06cc.png","status":1},{"id":5,"title":"\u0645\u06cc\u0648\u0647 \u0647\u0627\u06cc \u062a\u0627\u0632\u0647 \u0631\u0648\u0632\u0627\u0646\u0647","photo":"\/upload\/slider\/2021\/1\/\u0645\u06cc\u0648\u0647 \u0647\u0627\u06cc \u062a\u0627\u0632\u0647 \u0631\u0648\u0632\u0627\u0646\u0647\/\u0645\u06cc\u0648\u0647 \u0647\u0627\u06cc \u062a\u0627\u0632\u0647 \u0631\u0648\u0632\u0627\u0646\u0647.jpg","status":1}],"status":"success"}
```

How can I read and maybe convert this format to normal json utf-8 ?

Comment: what is the error you are facing when you try to access json?can you specify it in more details?

Comment: All the special characters there are escaped. It's ASCII.

Comment: @JatinParmar For example the photo variable value is not readable and doesn't work , it's not normal json format

Comment: i have just copied you json and paste inside console, it seems okay,yet can you specify the error message?